# SilverStripe 3 - Extending Comments Form

Tags: silverstripe

I'd like to extend AddCommentForm so I can output field labels with custom classes. I want to remove 'left' class from label as it conflicts with Foundation but ideally I want to have full control over outputted HTML.

I tried to extend CommentingController in mysite/code but no luck there...

Can I set it up so every field type has it's own .ss template?

How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SilverStripe you can overwrite templates just by creating a file of the same name in your `mysite` or theme folder.

so, lets say you have a Form of the class `SomeForm` all you need to do is create a file called `SomeForm.ss` and SilverStripe will use that instead of the default `Form.ss`.

However, the css class 'left' is not added in `Form.ss`, in that template there is only the form html, the fields are added in a loop.
(Also, the comment module does not use a class for the Form, so that won't work here anyway.)

Each field has its own template (actually 2 templates). `MyField.ss` and `MyField_holder.ss`.
If one of the 2 templates does not exist, it will fall back to the default files `FormField.ss` and `FormField_holder.ss`.

so lets take for example the class `TextField`, it will use:

- `FormField_holder.ss` because there is no `TextField_holder.ss`
- `TextField.ss`

the `<label>` you seek is inside `FormField_holder.ss`.
You could of course just create a `FormField_holder.ss` and copy the [Content from the original file](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/2427d57fa54659f7ee17b79c4a31deec036ce9a3/templates/forms/FormField_holder.ss), but this would also effect the CMS. So you need some way to only effect the frontend.

Unfortunately, I don't really have nice and clean a solution for this problem. 
Usually I would recommend sub classing that form and overwriting the template for the Fields in a loop.
But I think you are using this module here: https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-comments/ which does no use a class for that form, so we have to use a work around and hook into that controller.

---

File **MyCommentControllerExntesion**:

```
class MyCommentControllerExntesion extends Extension {
    public function alterCommentForm($form) {
        foreach($form->Fields() as $field) {
            if (!$field->is_a('HiddenField') {
                // skip hidden fields
                $field->setFieldHolderTemplate('MyFrontEndField_holder');
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

File **config.yml**:

```
CommentingController:
  extensions:
    - 'MyCommentControllerExntesion'
```

File **MyFrontEndField_holder.ss**:

```
<div id="$Name" class="field<% if $extraClass %> $extraClass<% end_if %>">
    <% if $Title %><label class="not-left" for="$ID">$Title</label><% end_if %>
    <div class="middleColumn">
        $Field
    </div>
    <% if $RightTitle %><label class="right" for="$ID">$RightTitle</label><% end_if %>
    <% if $Message %><span class="message $MessageType">$Message</span><% end_if %>
    <% if $Description %><span class="description">$Description</span><% end_if %>
</div>
```

Comment: @Zauberfish
Man, that IS great help - exactly what I was looking for!
SilverStripe 3 is a great system but lacks advanced tutorials. I'm not afraid of getting my hands dirty with PHP but it's rarely obvious where to put my subclasses.
Thanks a bunch!

Comment: np. yeah, its a know problem with silverstripe, not enough good docs. feel free to keep asking questions here or on IRC though, the SilverStripe community might be small, but the help one gets is usually pretty good.

Comment: To be sure:
I add MyCommentControllerExtension to mysite/code?
Shouldn't it extend CommentsExtension?
And .ss files goes to mytemplate/templates or mytemplate/templates/Includes?

I did it all but no effect...

Comment: 1) yes. php files go into `mysite/code`; 2) doesn't matter I think; 3) ss files either into `mysite/templates` or `themes/mytheme/templates`; 4) don't forget to visit your site with `/?flush=all` to flush the cache. both templates and extensions are cached